# Using MemoryAppender along with FileAppender in log4net

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I was using a FileAppender to log to a file in my application.
Now i started using MemoryAppender to get errors from the log and store them in a database.This is for showing up the exceptions/errors on the ui where i query the database.

While i see the errors properly inserted into the database , i see that they are missing from the logs.

I read somewhere that a MemoryAppender only writes to memory.
But when i have both FileAppender and MemoryAppender configured, isn't it also supposed to write to the log file?

Is there a workaround where i can still have the errors logged to the file?

Answer (score 0):

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Use this link to store the logs in database.I have tried its working fine.then you will get a log info from the db to grid or anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you use the MemoryAppender for. You can use the AdoNetAppender and store log entries directly to the database.

If I understand correctly, then your question was about the missing logs in the file. Log4net should sends all log entries to all configured appenders unless you have explicitly configured it not to do so. I do not assume that you have any filters configured that prevent some messages from being written to the file. So maybe you have locking issues with files (internal debugging should reveal this problem, see [log4net FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)).

If that is the case you can try to use this for your file appender:

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

This however has an impact on performance and you should try to figure out why you have locking issues.